# dcm4chee - Getting values of Class SOP UID and Transfer Syntax UID

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I want to get this uid in order to get the file from dicom server as these parameters are needed by the function `addStoreTransferCapability`.The kit I am using is dcm4chee and the language is java.

Comment: What problems are you having finding these values?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its returning null following is the code:



       dcmqr.setQueryLevel(DcmQR.QueryRetrieveLevel.PATIENT);
       
              dcmqr.setQueryLevel(DcmQR.QueryRetrieveLevel.STUDY);
               
               dcmqr.setQueryLevel(DcmQR.QueryRetrieveLevel.SERIES);
                
                
              dcmqr.setQueryLevel(DcmQR.QueryRetrieveLevel.IMAGE);
      
                dcmqr.addReturnKey(Tag.toTagPath("SOPClassUID"));
                dcmqr.addReturnKey(Tag.toTagPath("PatientName"));
                dcmqr.addReturnKey(Tag.toTagPath("StudyInstanceUID"));

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question with your specific issue and what you've tried. It's not clear what is null from your code, nor how it relates to your original issue. Again, stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually I cant ask further questions:
Here is what is happening in the above code I am setting the query level and the return keys I have also set TransferSyntaxUID as a return key . Query is  being made and when I check the results for tsuid it returns null.



dcmqr.addReturnKey(Tag.toTagPath("TransferSyntaxUID"));
 System.out.print("Here are the tags:"+ result.get(0).getString(Tag.TransferSyntaxUID)+ "\n");

Answer (score 0):

The TransferSyntaxUID is not a subject to the persistent storage of the DICOM object, it is rather used in "presentation context negotiation" - which format can the sender provide and which format can the receiver accept - when the image is actually transferred. That is why you cannot query for it in a C-FIND request (I suppose that is what you are doing).

Why do you think that you want to query for it?

(I apologize for not posting this as a comment, but I am new to stackoverflow and do not have sufficient reputation to do so).

Comment: You cannot "query to retrieve". Query (C-FIND) and retrieve (C-MOVE) are different services. The typical process is: 1: Query for a study by specifying patient and study attributes in a C-FIND request. 2: Trigger a C-MOVE-request conveying the StudyInstanceUID received through C-FIND and the destination AET.  3: The C-MOVE request should trigger a C-STORE request to your system on the remote server. Your Storage Service Class Provider will then receive a list of presentation contexts in association negotiation. Then you can decide which Transfersyntax is accepted on your end.

Comment: DICOM object transfer involves a lot of knowledge of the DICOM standard. I can highly recommend this great introduction: http://www.course-as.ru/download/pdf/DICOM/CookBook.pdf

Comment: For this process I am using dcm4chee kit wirtten in java. It has a function named addStoreTransferCapability that requires two inputs as arguments one is SOPclass uid and other is transfer syntax UID (data type an array of strings ) so is anywhere defined number of transfer syntax uids ??? or

Comment: Not sure if there is a complete table somewhere in the standard. I like to use the one of my favorite DICOM toolkit: http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcuid_8h-source.html

Comment: ok I moved a bit when I query at image level in order to get the images I get error missing unique key attribute (0020,000E) at series level

Comment: In this case:  You have to include the identifying information from the  higher levels: Pat-ID, Study UID, Series UID. Sorry, I can just repeat my recommendation to get familiar with the DICOM standard first or use a toolkit that does not require knowledge of the DICOM standard.